# Downgrading from iOS 8.1 beta 2 to iOS 8.0.2

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have to use a backup of my iPhone but iTunes says that is not compatible with 
the beta distribution. So I need to downgrade to iOS 8.0.2 but it seems not possible.

Any Idea?

Now I'm downloading it (iOS 8.0.2) manually and I'll try to replace manually.

Comment: What you are doing should work, however, I don't think we are supposed to discuss beta/prerelease software issues here.

Comment: I'm posting the answer. Why we can't discuss beta software issues? I'm a developer, I'm not haking my phone (JZsystem)

Comment: See http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-8-and-os-x-yosemite-questions-ok?cb=1 answer 2.

Comment: If you are a developer having an issues with a beta of iOS then you should be posting it in the forums that Apple provides to developers who are using the betas of iOS, not here.

Comment: We considered downgrading from Yosemite to Mavericks on-topic, let's try to stick to the same rule for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

The only method is this:

- Be prepared to LOSE ALL DATA, so do the proper backup.
- Turn off the iPhone.
- Push the Home button until the iTunes icon on the iPhone appears red.
- Connect it to your computer and do the restore.

iTunes will, at this point, download the last official release of iOS. And, keep in mind, you will LOSE ALL DATA.